# What is the output meaning of ss -p

Tags: linux, networking

When I use the `-p` or `--processes` option, I get the output like this:

```
LISTEN   0   511   ...   ...   users:(("nginx",4209,255),("nginx",18819,255))
```

I know `("nginx",4209,255)` means the *nginx process* with *pid 4209* is using the socket, but what is the meaning of *255*, what does it stand for?

I looked up in manuals but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's file number descriptor. You can read [these line from source code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ss.c#n574) to see it.

On Debian system, you will get a better output:

```
tcp    ESTAB      0      0   ...      ...    users:(("skype",pid=3074,fd=67))
```

Base on your output, I guess you're on a Redhat or Ubuntu base systems.

Comment: Cuong, Ubuntu also does not show `fd` in front..

Comment: @heemayl: Yes, I also checked with Linux Mint. It seems that Redhat base and Ubuntu base don't show it.